# If someone has a photocopy of my passport, could they steal my identity?

Tags: passports, identity-cards

Someone has taken a copy of my passport and other identification.

Does that mean it's possible for someone to steal my identity?

Comment: Not sure how this is related to travel.  But https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assassination_of_Mahmoud_Al-Mabhouh

Comment: [This post](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41095/419-nigerian-scam-problem/41098#41098) in Security.SE is discussing this..